# ¿Cómo enviar una petición ajax cuando el usuario cierre la pestaña/navegador?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy haciendo una tabla HTML para gestionar datos, que, en principio, he limitado que sea abierta por un usuario a la vez.

Para ello, existe una tabla `user_service` que lleva el control de qué usuario está modificando qué servicio.

Lo que estoy intentando hacer ahora es detectar cuándo ese usuario ha terminado de editar esa tabla, para ello, me gustaría detectar cuando cierre el navegador o la pestaña para recibir una petición ajax y borrar la fila en la tabla `user_service`.

Lo único que encuentro son referencias a la función: `beforeunload`

Ejemplo:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = '';
});
```

Pero esto no aplica para lo que busco.

Comment: Por qué no aplica a lo que buscas? Qué te impide enviar una petición `ajax` cuando se dispare ese evento?

Comment: El mensaje por defecto no se puede cambiar y eso es un problema, entonces te pregunto ¿puedo detectar cuando el usuario haga clic en "confirmar" de esa ventana? (O sea, de la ventana con el mensaje que aparece después del evento)

Comment: Si te fijas, el mensaje no se cambia en ninguno de los navegadores. No es un problema, así está diseñado. Si estás en desacuerdo, puedes enviar tu propuesta al equipo de Chrome, Firefox, Edge, etc. Alternativamente, puedes intentar usar el evento `unload`, que [viene después](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/page-lifecycle-api/) del `beforeunload`.

Answer (score 0):

si intentas capturar el evento colocándolo de la  siguiente forma puede que reconozcas mejor el evento y hacer tus peticiones

```
<body onbeforeunload="return myFunction()">
  <h1>hola mundo</h1>
</body>

</script>
  function myFunction() {
   
    return "Write something clever here...";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: No me deja personalizar el mensaje de la ventana que sale al utilizar ese evento. Parece que ante sí se podía, pero en los navegadores modernos no se puede por temas de seguridad. Pensaba delegar la responsabilidad al usuario, es decir, poner un mensaje personalizado "Si no has guardado, perderás todo" pero al no poder personalizarlo debo buscar otra solución, es decir, intentar detectar yo mismo cuando ha dejado de trabajar. ¿Hay forma de detectar si el usuario ha dado en "confirmar" de esa ventana que sale al usar onbeforeunload()?